# Custom radio-button INI page via Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, custom-controls, nsis

I'm using Eclipse's create InstallOptions menu to create a custom INI page with radio-buttons for repackaging the Blackberry Desktop installer.

There are 2 sections for each type: "Internet" and "Enterprise".

I need a user to select 1 of the 2 options and depending on their selection, the page will carry over the selection chosen in the custom page, jump to the INSTFILES page, and continue onto the end.

I couldn't find any concrete documentation on getting INI pages to load in the script (I'm probably searching incorrectly), and then pass data from one page to the next (according to fields I guess?)

Any help is appreciated. Even if it's to tell me I'm blind and can't read a doc (though a link would help :) )

Here's the INI code:

---

; Auto-generated by EclipseNSIS InstallOptions Script Wizard
; Jul 29, 2009 5:42:56 PM

[Settings]
NumFields=7
Title=RIM BlackBerry Desktop 5.0 installation
CancelEnabled=1

[Field 1]
Type=RadioButton
Left=15
Top=28
Right=100
Bottom=38
Text=Internet
State=
Flags=NOTIFY

[Field 4]
Type=RadioButton
Left=15
Top=95
Right=100
Bottom=105
Text=Enterprise
Flags=NOTIFY

[Field 2]
Type=GroupBox
Left=0
Top=10
Right=300
Bottom=75
Text=

[Field 5]
Type=Label
Left=30
Top=42
Right=235
Bottom=52
Text=For users who are NOT on the Enterprise (Exchange) server

[Field 6]
Type=Label
Left=30
Top=111
Right=235
Bottom=121
Text=Choose this only if you are on the Exchange server

[Field 3]
Type=GroupBox
Left=0
Top=75
Right=300
Bottom=140

[Field 7]
Type=Label
Left=0
Top=0
Right=130
Bottom=10
Text=Please choose your installation method

---

...And here's the NSI code:

---

Auto-generated by EclipseNSIS Script Wizard
Jul 29, 2009 5:42:16 PM

Name "BlackBerry Desktop"

RequestExecutionLevel admin

General Symbol Definitions
!define VERSION 5.0.0.11
!define COMPANY RIM
!define URL http://www.blackberry.com

MUI Symbol Definitions
!define MUI_ICON BBD.ico
!define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_RADIOBUTTONS

Included files
!include Sections.nsh
!include MUI2.nsh

Reserved Files
ReserveFile "${NSISDIR}\Plugins\AdvSplash.dll"

Installer pages
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE license.txt
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
Installer languages
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Installer attributes
OutFile RIM_BlackBerry_Desktop_5.0.exe
InstallDir "$TEMP\RIM BlackBerry Desktop 5.0 Setup Files"
CRCCheck on
XPStyle on
ShowInstDetails hide
VIProductVersion 5.0.0.11
VIAddVersionKey /LANG=${LANG_ENGLISH} ProductName "BlackBerry Desktop"
VIAddVersionKey /LANG=${LANG_ENGLISH} ProductVersion "${VERSION}"
VIAddVersionKey /LANG=${LANG_ENGLISH} CompanyName "${COMPANY}"
VIAddVersionKey /LANG=${LANG_ENGLISH} CompanyWebsite "${URL}"
VIAddVersionKey /LANG=${LANG_ENGLISH} FileVersion "${VERSION}"
VIAddVersionKey /LANG=${LANG_ENGLISH} FileDescription ""
VIAddVersionKey /LANG=${LANG_ENGLISH} LegalCopyright ""

Installer sections
Section /o Main SEC0000
SetOutPath $INSTDIR
SetOverwrite ifdiff
; TESTING PHASE    
SectionEnd

SectionGroup /e "BlackBerry Desktop Section"
Section /o Internet SEC0001
SetOutPath $INSTDIR\DRIVERS
SetOverwrite ifdiff
;    Execwait 'msiexec /i "$INSTDIR\BlackBerry USB and Modem Drivers_ENG (DM5.0b28).msi" /passive'    
SetOutPath $INSTDIR
SetOverwrite ifdiff
;    File /r *
;    ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\Setup.exe" /S/v/qb!'
SectionEnd

Section /o Enterprise SEC0002
SetOutPath $INSTDIR\DRIVERS
SetOverwrite ifdiff
;    Execwait 'msiexec /i "$INSTDIR\BlackBerry USB and Modem Drivers_ENG (DM5.0b28).msi" /passive'  
SetOutPath $INSTDIR
SetOverwrite ifdiff
;    File /r * 
;    Delete /REBOOTOK "$INSTDIR\Setup.ini" 
;    Rename /REBOOTOK "$INSTDIR\Setup_Enterprise.ini" "$INSTDIR\Setup.ini" 
;    ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\Setup.exe" /S/v/qb!' 
SectionEnd 
SectionGroupEnd

Section Descriptions 
!insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_BEGIN 
!insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${SEC0000} $(SEC0000_DESC) 
!insertmacro MUI_DESCRIPTION_TEXT ${SEC0001} $(SEC0001_DESC) 
!insertmacro MUI_FUNCTION_DESCRIPTION_END

Installer Language Strings 
TODO Update the Language Strings with the appropriate translations.

LangString SEC0000_DESC ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Installation for non-Exchange/Enterprise BlackBerry Users" 
LangString SEC0001_DESC ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Installation for Exchange/Enterprise BlackBerry Users"

Answer (score 0):

You could start by creating a global variable with `Var IsEnterprise` or something like that.

To get the actual page working, you would insert a page command somewhere between your existing MUI_PAGE macros

```
page EnterprisePageCreate EnterprisePageLeave
```

EnterprisePageCreate and EnterprisePageLeave should be nsis functions, the create function should create the page and the leave function should get the state from the radio buttons and save it in your global $IsEnterprise (You can find the info on how to do this in the InstallOptions readme and examples)

Then later on you could use $IsEnterprise in a section.

But since you already have a section called Enterprise, I would assume that you just want to toggle this section. If that is the case, there is no need to save the state in a var, you could toggle the sections "checkbox" with the macros in sections.nsh in the EnterprisePageLeave function.

You also mention that you want to jump to the InstFiles page, looking at the script you posted, I would just put the custom page before the components page and when Enterprise radio is on, turn on the section, otherwise, turn it off and make it read only.

---

On a unrelated note, just using `RequestExecutionLevel admin` is not enough, when UAC is off or < Vista, you need to use the UserInfo plugin to detect if the user is admin or not.

Comment: I'm also looking into nsDialogs.  Quite a bit different than InstallOptions, but supposedly can use an INI.

I have the functions down and working, but just need it to take the GetState variables and pass them along to the sections I have for Internet/Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing using nsDialogs.  No GUI, but more control from a design standpoint it seems.

Got the Radio-button page to work fine, except that it shows the custom page with the 'License Agreement' Subcaption when the installer runs.

NSI Code:

> Name "BlackBerry Desktop"
>
> RequestExecutionLevel admin
>
> General Symbol Definitions  
>   !define VERSION 5.0.0.11 
>   !define COMPANY RIM 
>   !define URL http://www.blackberry.com
>
> MUI Symbol Definitions  
>   !define MUI_ICON Blackberry.ico  
>   !define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_RADIOBUTTONS
>
> Included files  
>   !include Sections.nsh  
>   !include MUI2.nsh  
>   !include nsDialogs.nsh  
>   !include LogicLib.nsh
>
> Variables 
>   Var /GLOBAL AccountType 
>   Var InstallerSelect 
>   Var Label  
>   Var Label_2 
>   Var Label_3  
>   Var RadioButton_1 
>   Var RadioButton_2  
>   Var /GLOBAL RadioButton_1_State  
>   Var /GLOBAL RadioButton_2_State
>
> Reserved Files  
>   ReserveFile "${NSISDIR}\Plugins\AdvSplash.dll"
>
> Installer pages  
>   !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME  
>   !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE license.txt  
>   ;Page Custom InstallerSelect InstallerSelectLeave  
>   PageEx custom 
>       PageCallbacks InstallerSelect InstallerSelectLeave 
>       Caption " "  
>   PageExEnd  
>   !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES  
>   !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH 
>    Installer languages 
>   !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
>
> Installer attributes  
>   OutFile "RIM_BlackBerry_Desktop_5.0.exe" 
>   InstallDir "$TEMP\RIM BlackBerry Desktop 5.0 Setup Files" 
>   CRCCheck on 
>   XPStyle on 
>   ShowInstDetails hide 
>   VIProductVersion 5.0.0.11 
>   VIAddVersionKey /LANG=${LANG_ENGLISH} 
>   ProductName "BlackBerry Desktop" 
>   VIAddVersionKey /LANG=${LANG_ENGLISH} 
>   ProductVersion "${VERSION}" 
>   VIAddVersionKey /LANG=${LANG_ENGLISH} 
>   CompanyName "${COMPANY}" 
>   VIAddVersionKey /LANG=${LANG_ENGLISH} 
>   CompanyWebsite "${URL}" 
>   VIAddVersionKey /LANG=${LANG_ENGLISH} 
>   FileVersion "${VERSION}" 
>   VIAddVersionKey /LANG=${LANG_ENGLISH} 
>   FileDescription "" VIAddVersionKey 
>   /LANG=${LANG_ENGLISH} LegalCopyright ""
>
> ;Check Admin Function  
>   Function CheckAdmin  
>   ; Check if the current user has Administrator rights 
>       userInfo::getAccountType 
>       pop $AccountType 
>       strCmp $AccountType "Admin" +3 
>       messageBox MB_OK "You do not have Administrator rights.$\n$\nInstallation cancelled" 
>       Quit 
>       return 
>   FunctionEnd
>
> ;Select Installation-type Page Functions  
>   Function InstallerSelect 
>           nsDialogs::create 1018 
>           Pop $InstallerSelect
>
> ```
>     ${If} $InstallerSelect == error <br>
>             Abort <br>
>     ${EndIf} <br>
>
>     ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "Please select an installation type..." <br>
>     Pop $Label <br>
>
>     ${NSD_CreateLabel} 10% 30% 90% 20 "For users who are NOT on the Enterprise (Exchange) server" <br>
>     Pop $Label_2 <br>
>
>     ${NSD_CreateLabel} 10% 70% 90% 20 "For users who are on the Enterprise (Exchange) server" <br>
>     Pop $Label_3         <br>
>
>     ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 5% 20% 100% 20 "Internet" <br>
>     Pop $RadioButton_1 <br>
>
>     ${NSD_CreateRadioButton} 5% 60% 100% 20 "Enterprise" <br>
>     Pop $RadioButton_2 <br>
>
>     ${If} $RadioButton_1_State == ${BST_CHECKED} <br>
>             ${NSD_Check} $RadioButton_1 <br>
>     ${EndIf}  <br>
>
>     ${If} $RadioButton_2_State == ${BST_CHECKED} <br>
>             ${NSD_Check} $RadioButton_2 <br>
>     ${EndIf} <br>
>
>     nsDialogs::Show  <br>
> ```
>
> FunctionEnd
>
> Function InstallerSelectLeave 
>           ${NSD_GetState} $RadioButton_1 $RadioButton_1_State 
>           ${NSD_GetState} $RadioButton_2 $RadioButton_2_State 
>   FunctionEnd
>
> Installer sections
>
> Section -Main SEC0000 
>       Call CheckAdmin
>
> ```
> SetOutPath $INSTDIR\BB_MS
> SetOverwrite ifdiff
> File /r BB_MS\*
> SetOutPath $INSTDIR\Drivers
> SetOverwrite ifdiff
> File /r DRIVERS\*
> SetOutPath $INSTDIR\ISSetupPrerequisites
> SetOverwrite ifdiff
> File /r ISSetupPrerequisites\*
> SetOutPath $INSTDIR
> SetOverwrite ifdiff
> File "_setup.exe"
> File "0x0409.ini"
> File "Autorun.inf"
> File "BBDMUtil.dll"
> File "BlackBerry Desktop Software.msi"
> File "BlackBerrySetup.exe"
> File "Data1.cab"
> File "FLEXnet_patch_Q113020.exe"
> File "install.txt"
> File "install_ENT_silent.cmd"
> File "install_ENT_ui.cmd"
> File "install_INT_silent.cmd"
> File "install_INT_ui.cmd"
> File "setup.bmp"
> File "Setup_Internet.ini"
> File "Setup_Enterprise.ini"
> File "WindowsInstaller-KB893803-x86.exe"
> ```
>
> ; Checks selected installation method 
>       StrCmp $RadioButton_1_State 1 Internet 0 
>       StrCmp $RadioButton_2_State 1 Enterprise Internet
>
> ```
>  Internet: <br>
> Execwait 'msiexec /i "$INSTDIR\Drivers\BlackBerry USB and Modem Drivers_ENG (DM5.0b28).msi" /passive /norestart' <br>
> Rename "$INSTDIR\Setup_Internet.ini" "$INSTDIR\Setup.ini" <br>
> Sleep 1000 <br>
> ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\BlackBerrySetup.exe" /S /v/passive' <br>
>     Goto End <br>
> ```
>
> Enterprise:  
>       Execwait 'msiexec /i "$INSTDIR\Drivers\BlackBerry USB and Modem Drivers_ENG (DM5.0b28).msi" /passive /norestart' 
>       Rename "$INSTDIR\Setup_Enterprise.ini" "$INSTDIR\Setup.ini" 
>       Sleep 1000 
>       ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\BlackBerrySetup.exe" /S /v/passive'
>
> END: 
>   SectionEnd
>
> Installer functions  
>   Function .onInit 
>       InitPluginsDir 
>       Push $R1 
>       File /oname=$PLUGINSDIR\spltmp.bmp Blackberry.bmp 
>       advsplash::show 1000 600 400 0x666666 $PLUGINSDIR\spltmp 
>       Pop $R1 
>       Pop $R1 FunctionEnd